# Convert or replace interval objects with integer values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am successfully binning some data with this:

```
temp['category_fare'] = pd.qcut(train['Fare'], 4)
```

I get this as output:

```
       category_fare
0     (-0.001, 7.91]
1    (31.0, 512.329]
2     (7.91, 14.454]
3    (31.0, 512.329]
4     (7.91, 14.454]
..               ...
886   (7.91, 14.454]
887   (14.454, 31.0]
888   (14.454, 31.0]
889   (14.454, 31.0]
890   (-0.001, 7.91]
```

But what I really want is to replace each of the four category intervals with an integer:

```
(-0.001, 7.91] = 0
(7.91, 14.454] = 1
(14.454, 31.0] = 2
(31.0, 512.329] = 3
```

I tried using replace but it does not work.  Replace is trying to replace a string (that's how I fed it to replace) but in my debugger I see those are interval objects(?):

```
(0, Interval(-0.001, 7.91, closed='right')) (1, Interval(31.0, 512.329, closed='right'))
```

Is there a way to either replace them with the corresponding int values from above, or even create a new column with the corresponding int values?

I do not know how to reference an interval object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `labels=False` parameter in [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html):

> labels : array or boolean, default None
>
> Used as labels for the resulting bins. Must be of the same length as the resulting bins. **If False, return only integer indicators of the bins**.

```
temp['category_fare'] = pd.qcut(train['Fare'], 4, labels=False)
```

Comment: The `labels=False` is right choice.  But it may be useful to know that with `labels=True`, `pd.qcut` produces a catdgorical dtype and the integer factorization can be accessed with `pd.qcut(train['Fare'], 4).cat.codes`.  @jezrael, this comment is for everyone else (-: